# ColdFusion 10 call to .Net results in missing method error

Tags: .net, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I have a .Net DLL built in VS2008 which transfers information to an external system from ColdFusion.  We have had this installed and running in our datacenter for one of our hosted clients for six months or so.  We are working with another client to set this up in his environment, but are receiving an error indicating that the method cannot be found:

```
"Information","ajp-bio-8012-exec-1","12/29/15","15:14:32",,"Either there are no methods with the specified method name and argument types or the SendStudentAccountTransaction method is overloaded with argument types that ColdFusion cannot decipher reliably. ColdFusion found 0 methods that match the provided arguments. If this is a Java object and you verified that the method exists, use the javacast function to reduce ambiguity."
"Information","ajp-bio-8012-exec-1","12/29/15","15:14:32",,"The SendStudentAccountTransaction method was not found."
```

The code looks something like this:

```
<cfif qBilling.RecordCount GT 0>
<cfscript>
    ASI2Banner = CreateObject(".NET","ASIBanner.Sender","C:\ASIBanner\ASIBanner.dll");
</cfscript>
<cfdump var="#ASI2Banner#" />
<CFLOOP query="qBilling">
    <cflog file="#logfile_name#" text="Sending: #qBilling.TimeframeNumericCode#, #qBilling.StudentNumber#, #qBilling.Account#, #qBilling.Amount#, #qBilling.TxDate#, #qBilling.EffectiveDate#, #qBilling.TxDescription#, #qBilling.StudentBillingInternalID#, '', '', 'Y', 'Y', '', '', 'ASIBanner_Test.txt'" />
    <cfset result = ASI2Banner.SendStudentAccountTransaction("#qBilling.TimeframeNumericCode#", "#qBilling.StudentNumber#", "#qBilling.Account#", "#qBilling.Amount#", "#qBilling.TxDate#", "#qBilling.EffectiveDate#", "#qBilling.TxDescription#", "#qBilling.StudentBillingInternalID#", "", "", "Y", "Y", "", "", "ASIBanner_Test.txt") />
    <cflog file="#logfile_name#" text="Result: #result#" />
```

We are getting log entries that do verify that we have records to export, that the ASIBanner.Sender object has been created, and that the script is attempting to send the first record; however, there is no entry for the result of the call, indicating it is not completing. The error is occurring on the line:
 `<cfset result = ASI2Banner.SendStudentAccountTransaction("#qBilling.TimeframeNumericCode#", "#qBilling.StudentNumber#", "#qBilling.Account#", "#qBilling.Amount#", "#qBilling.TxDate#", "#qBilling.EffectiveDate#", "#qBilling.TxDescription#", "#qBilling.StudentBillingInternalID#", "", "", "Y", "Y", "", "", "ASIBanner_Test.txt") />
        <cflog file="#logfile_name#" text="Result: #result#" />`

The results of the cfdump upon creating the object shows that the ASIBanner.Sender class does expose the SendStudentAccountTransaction() method:
[CFDUMP of var ASI2Banner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXyRg.png)

I have also verified that the parameter count and type match.  I am getting the same results regardless of whether or not I explicitly setup a proxy via JNBProxyGUI.exe (when trying this with the proxy, I did include the jar file in the path when creating the object).

We have uninstalled and re-installed ColdFusion, the CF DotNet service, and have updated the JRE to 1.8.0.65, all without success.  I have verified that the DLL is not marked as blocked, and that the correct .Net framework is bound to the application pool in IIS.  I have cleaned out the {cfusion}\wwwroot\WEB-INF\cfclasses\dotNetProxy folder (save dotNetCoreProxy.jar).

What is absolutely maddening is that this same code is working flawlessly on what appears to be an identically configured server in our environment.  I know I have to be missing something, I just don't see what it is.

Comment: Have you checked whether the other methods of your `ASI2Banner` object do work?

Comment: Same results - they work as expected in our environment, but yield the same error on his.

Comment: That is a puzzler. Sounds like you have tried all the usual suspects. *RE: what appears to be an identically configured server*  Silly question, but are you saying you verified the full version numbers of CF 10.x.xxx, JVM, IIS, .NET framework, etc... are ALL identical? Also, shot in the dark but A) did you check the logs for any additional errors B) While I doubt it is the issue, is your test script using a manual query ie `queryNew` with hard coded values, just to rule out data based issues.

Comment: C) Can run you *any* custom assemblies on that server successfully?

Comment: Version numbers for CF10, JVM, IIS, and .Net Framework were all confirmed identical.  ProcMon.exe has not yielded any clues, either.  Oddly, I have found a message  in the ColdFusion error log pointing to a "com.sun.star.lib.loader.Loader::getCustomLoader: no UNO installation found!" which appears to be related to the use of Open Office (we are not using it in our hosted environment, I will need to verify with the client about his site).

Comment: Data in qBilling has been verified to be non-null strings.

Comment: (Edit) @L.Wingerd - I do not think OpenOffice error is related, unless you are using something that requires it (sounds like no). I know there are log files in a few locations, did you check all of them on the problem server (maybe search by modified date)? As far as the data, I still recommend a hard coded test if possible. While it is probably not a data issue, running the exact same code would let you definitively rule out data related factors. Also, what about question C) Can you run *any* assemblies on that server?

Comment: I'm able to launch the same assembly and get good results on multiple methods using a test application written in VS; however, still no joy using CF.